# Javascript - how to give an id name with querySelector followed by a incremented number?

Tags: javascript, html

I add a row to an array using the javascript clone function and I want an element of my new row, namely an input, to take an id name followed by a number corresponding to its rank.

For example, if I add a row, the input thus created will have the id "HiddenBox1". If I add another one, it will have the id "HiddenBox2", and so on.

The following script allows to increment the first input "id=boxHidden" to 0 (id="0") after submitting (button 'Add') but can't replace the next "id=boxHidden" by id="1" and the following one by id="2", and so on. Solution ? Thanks for help !

```
<script>
function addRow() {
    const table = document.querySelector('#tbl_usr_task'); //id of the table
    const tfoot = table.querySelector('tfoot'); //tfoot of the table
    const emptyRow = tfoot.querySelector('tr:nth-child(2)'); // the line (tr) I want to clone
    const clone = emptyRow.cloneNode(true);
    clone.querySelector('th').innerHTML = '';
    tfoot.appendChild(clone); // the clone
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(2)'), function() {
        var div_array = [...document.querySelector('td:nth-child(8)').querySelectorAll('#boxHidden')]; // converts NodeList to Array
        div_array.forEach((v,i)=>v.id=i+0);
    });
}
</script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light add-more" onclick="addRow();">Add</button>
```

```
<tr>
  <th style="display: none">              
     &nbsp;      
  </th> 

  <td>  
    <input id="boxHidden" type='hidden' name='ovr_ms[]' value='0' />   
    <input id="boxVisible" type="checkbox" name="ovr_ms[]" value='1' onclick="disableHiddenBox()"/> 
  </td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: Never use `id` attributes in dynamic content. Use `class` attributes, and relate the content to each other using DOM traversal

Comment: consider using a generator function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

Comment: instead of chaining querySelectors, you could just have `'td:nth-child(8) input'`  first of all. If you really had to, you could ``const rows = tfoot.find('tr').length; const newid = `hiddenbox-${rows+1}` `` but I agree it would be a bad idea. You could anyway get there with `tfoot tr:nth-child(#i) input`

Comment: Your `clone` variable holds the complete object model of the cloned row. Find the input element in that object model and set its `id` attribute. You haven't included the HTML for the row, so we can't provide any help in finding that element. However, as others have noted, using `id` may not be the best idea. There may be better ways to accomplish your actual goals.

Comment: BTW: maybe better to set the input's `name` instead of it's ID